# Line separator missing on removing a div

Tags: html, css

I'm having an HTML code In which I'm showing a line in between the elements as shown in the below code snippet.

```css
 .iqalJN{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr auto;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 2rem; 
    column-gap: 2rem;
 }
 .btn-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    column-gap: 0.5rem;
}
 
 hr{ 
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
 
  
  <section class="sc-jSMfEi iqalJN">
  <div class="btn-container"></div>
  <p>Showing 1 to 20 of 87 Results</p>
  <hr/>
  <form>
    <label for="sort">sort by</label><select name="sort" id="sort" class="sort-input">
      <option value="Price: High to Low">Price: High to Low</option>
      <option value="Price: Low to High">Price: Low to High</option>
      <option value="Name: A-Z">Name: A-Z</option>
      <option value="Name: Z-A">Name: Z-A</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</section>
```

And when I remove the `div`, the line is disappearing, please run the below snippet to see the result.

```css
 .iqalJN{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr auto;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 2rem; 
    column-gap: 2rem;
 }
 .btn-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    column-gap: 0.5rem;
}
 
 hr{ 
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
 
  
  <section class="sc-jSMfEi iqalJN">
   <p>Showing 1 to 20 of 87 Results</p>
  <hr/>
  <form>
    <label for="sort">sort by</label><select name="sort" id="sort" class="sort-input">
      <option value="Price: High to Low">Price: High to Low</option>
      <option value="Price: Low to High">Price: Low to High</option>
      <option value="Name: A-Z">Name: A-Z</option>
      <option value="Name: Z-A">Name: Z-A</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</section>
```

I am confused about how can I show the line with `p` pushed towards the left as the first element.

with `div`, it should show `div` `p` `hr` `form`.
without `div` it should show `p` `hr` `form`

please let me know how can I achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your parent element CSS! so just change the `grid-template-columns` 
 from ❌`auto auto 1fr auto` to ✅`auto 1fr auto`

because by deleting that element, now the auto width grid element becomes the `<hr>` HTML element, and here is the problem.

so delete just the that `auto` keyword and you solved it!

> for more details, here the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns

```css
/* parent */

.iqalJN {
    display: grid;
    /* here the solution */
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    column-gap: 2rem;
}

.btn-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    column-gap: 0.5rem;
}

hr {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<section class="sc-jSMfEi iqalJN">
        <p>Showing 1 to 20 of 87 Results</p>
        <hr/>
        <form>
            <label for="sort">sort by</label><select name="sort" id="sort" class="sort-input">
           <option value="Price: High to Low">Price: High to Low</option>
           <option value="Price: Low to High">Price: Low to High</option>
           <option value="Name: A-Z">Name: A-Z</option>
           <option value="Name: Z-A">Name: Z-A</option>
         </select>
        </form>
    </section>
```